# Remove duplicates that obtain by table join in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, duplicates

I have a table called Test1 in which there are 309 records and one column called product_label. There is another table called Test2 in which there are more than 1000000 records and has columns product_label,account_number, customer_ref etc. One product_label belongs to a particular account and an account belongs to a particular customer. I want to get the relevant account_numbers and customer_ref for the product_labels in Test1.
I tried inner joining two tables based on product_label. But it produces more than 309 rows. Is there any method in oracle to remove duplicates that obtain by table join.

Comment: For us it is not clear what the tables contain. Is `Test1` the product label table, i.e. are there 309 different product labels in your database? If that is so and one product_label belongs to a particular account, why is the `account_number` in table `Test2` and not table `Test1`? You would only choose such data model if you want to allow for multiple accounts per product label. And in that case: If there are different accounts for one product label in `Test2`, which do you want to show?

Comment: More often than not, the need for a DISTINCT in a join stems from the fact, that the join isn't really needed and should be replaced with an `EXISTS` clause. But without more details/example data, this is really hard to answer

Answer (score 0):

Without any sample data or query (which is difficult to debug if you can't see it), the most obvious "solution" is to

```
select DISTINCT
```

Another possibility is that `JOIN` and/or `WHERE` clause you used don't restrict number of rows *enough*, so you'll have to see whether there's something you can do about it.